# Today's-Date token for PDF

Tags: tokens

How can I automatically display today's date in a pdf or email. 
I tried the "thank you date" token but the date format is 12-31-15 12:30. I need December 31, 2015...
I tried plugging in this 
{$smarty.now|date_format}
Still didn't work. 
Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this would be a custom token to get it in the format that you're looking for, but it wouldn't be too difficult and I am pretty sure you'll be able to find one someone has already written -

Check out the bottom two links of this page:

https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=13757.0

The last post April 29: "We discovered at the sprint that just about everyone has written a token for this at some point"...

I think there was a good example on coleman's blog here, too, but the main content doesn't seem to be loading for me anymore:

https://civicrm.org/blog/colemanw/create-your-own-tokens-for-fun-and-profit (corrected link)

Comment: Thanks I used this token which worked perfectly https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.civitoken

Answer (score 6):

In order to get smarty to work in email templates you need to enable it editing the settings file `civicrm.settings.php`, as per CiviCRM [documentation](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Smarty+in+mail+templates):

```
if (!defined('CIVICRM_MAIL_SMARTY')) {
     define( 'CIVICRM_MAIL_SMARTY', 1 ); // default is: define( 'CIVICRM_MAIL_SMARTY', 0 );
}
```

With smarty enabled, the following snippet should output the desired date format:

```
{$smarty.now|date_format} // Output: Jan 12, 2016
{$smarty.now|date_format:"%B %e, %Y"} // Output: January 12, 2016
```

As Eli says and references Coleman post is a very good example, simply pasting his code into an existing extension, or creating one for your needs, will work.

Answer (score 4):

You could create a custom token and add the format you want. An example of such a token in a custom format (a long with lots of other tokens) you could find in the extension no.maf.tokens This extension contains specific tokens for a client and one of the tokens in the date of today in Norwegian.

See https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.no.maf.ext/blob/master/org.civicoop.no.maf.tokens/maf_tokens.php#L72

Answer (score 2):

This is posted as a comment in the top answer, but it deserves more visibility as an answer: You can install [Fuzion's Civitoken extension](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.civitoken).