# Is there a 'Token' for adding a date to a message template?

Tags: civimember

Is there a 'Token' for adding 'today's date' to a letter template to avoid having to add the date manually?

Comment: This seems similar to https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/8783/todays-date-token-for-pdf. For your purposes the extension it suggests is probably the easiest: https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.civitoken

Comment: maybe add that as an Answer Demerit?

Comment: I voted to close it as duplicate, since there already is the answer at the other link. So I figured it would be a bit inconsistent to then give a duplicate answer.

Comment: Jack - welcome to Stack exchange. Before posting a question you should always search through existing questions to see if it has already been asked (and hopefully answered) before, as I believe is the case for your question

Answer (score 0):

There is no token available to add current date. You can create a custom token using following two hooks.

- [hook_civicrm_tokens](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_tokens/)
- [hook_civicrm_tokenValues](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_tokenValues/)

Please review documentation on how to create custom tokens described there.